# Auth0 with Angular JS Refresh Token issue (unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I am trying the auth0 with AnguarJS and basic login functionality is working but when I am using the refreshToken for generating the new IdToken and passing the new generated idToken into API call but  somehow the API giving an unauthorized error even the refreshIdToken method returning a New token.

I am using this in the config file to generate a new token.

```
authProvider.init({
    domain: 'kumar.auth0.com',
    clientId: '812vcly1OgIwM3j13dzyZ34mMUMFPE1' 
});

var refreshingToken = null;
var idToken = null;    

jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function($http, jwtHelper, auth, AuthService, HttpRequest) {
     var user = AuthService.getUser() ? JSON.parse(AuthService.getUser()) : AuthService.getUser();

    if(user) {
        idToken = user.accessToken; 
        refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
    }

    if (!idToken || !refreshToken) {
        return null;
    }
    if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(idToken)) {  
        return auth.refreshIdToken(refreshToken).then(function(newToken) { 
         var user = AuthService.getUser() ? JSON.parse(AuthService.getUser()) : AuthService.getUser();

        user ?  user['accessToken'] = newToken : null;
            HttpRequest.setToken(newToken);
            AuthService.setUser(user, configurations.expiryTime);
            return newToken;
        });
    } else {
        return idToken;
     }   
};
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
```

Please help where at I am wrong.

Comment: Can you share the exact error and check your logs in Auth0 ?

Comment: @Abhishrek its giving only unauthorized  text in response  and can you please tell how can I check logs in Auth0

Comment: To check the Auth0 logs goto Dashboard > Logs